# Multiple datepicker problem with same ID

Tags: jquery, html, validation

here is my problem:

```
<input type="text" class="datepick1" id="date" />
<input type="text" class="datepick2" id="date" />
<input type="text" class="datepick3" id="date" />
```

then i apply datepicker on dom (by classname)

```
$('.datepick1').datepicker();
$('.datepick2').datepicker();
$('.datepick3').datepicker();
```

=> the three dom have datepicker but, onselect date, it change automatically the first one (datepick1)

HELP

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more about your problem? A bit of Source Code, formatting and more information would be helpful if you want good answers.

Comment: Validate. Validate. Validate. http://validator.w3.org/ If your markup is broken (hint: it is), it isn't unreasonable to expect that JS will break when it tries to manipulate it.

Comment: You have the idea behind classes and ids mixed up.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, it does seem that way. I couldn't be absolutely sure that there wouldn't be other `datepick1` class inputs on the page, so I left it out of my answer, but...

Answer (score 12):

Your three inputs have the same `id` attribute on them. You can't do that, `id` attributes [**must** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#concept-id). (Having the same `name`, on the other hand, is fine in forms -- and common, for instance for radio buttons.)

**Edit** So your code posted to the comment below wants to be changed to:

```
$('<td></td>').append(
    $(NewLivraison.template.date)
        .val(arguments.date_livraison)
        .attr('id','date_' + arguments.num) // <== Note it's "id" we're making unique
        .addClass('date_' + arguments.num)  // <== You can probably drop this entirely
        .datepicker()
).css('vertical-align','top');
```

Comment: so,
i have a loop (for(i=0;i<x;i++)) to add <tr> to a table (with many td), in each td i have an input id = date, and an UNIQUE class ('datepick'+i) 
then i apply a datepicker to each input after append. 
Here is a bit source code

[...]

append(
 $('<td></td>')
 .append(
$(NewLivraison.template.date)
.val(arguments.date_livraison)
    .attr('id','date')    .addClass('date_'+arguments.num)
    .datepicker()
    ).css('vertical-align','top')
   )

Comment: this add a datepicker to my input but if i select a date it change the first input (in first tr), but if i change the ID from 'date' to 'date_'+arguments.num => this work, this is how i resolved my problem...

Conclusion : if you apply a datepicker to an element, be sure that there is no other element in your page that have the same ID

Comment: btw, NewLivraison.template.date is something like "<input type=text/>

Comment: @namezero: But the point is, it doesn't matter if the *class* is unique, the *id* has to be unique, not the class. Classes don't have to be unique to each element (and are somewhat pointless if they are). Somewhere in that code above you have `.attr('id', 'date')` -- **that's** where your problem is, you need each one to have a *different* ID.

Answer (score 7):

Supposed to be like this

```
<input type="text" id="datepick1" class="date" />
<input type="text" id="datepick2" class="date" />
<input type="text" id="datepick3" class="date" />

$('.date').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 5):

the problem lies within the jquery datepicker code in the _attachHandlers function.
The argument to the function is the instance of the current datepicker 'inst'.
The correct input is inst.input.
But the 'id' is only a string representation and you can never get the correct input if you have duplicate id's.
The easy workaround is to replace the argument 'id' in the handler functions with the inst.input so it will point to the correct input.

Also if you take a closer look inside the handler functions then you can see they try reverse engineer through the id back to the correct input...
Yet it will get you the first matching element with that id witch is not what we'd want.

```
var target = $(id),
    inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
```

And as $(inst.input) returns us inst.input we can easily fix it with this tiny adjustment.

Cheers

Original jquery code ui.1.10.3

```
    _attachHandlers: function(inst) {
        var stepMonths = this._get(inst, "stepMonths"),
            id = "#" + inst.id.replace( /\\\\/g, "\\" );
        inst.dpDiv.find("[data-handler]").map(function () {
            var handler = {
                prev: function () {
                    $.datepicker._adjustDate(id, -stepMonths, "M");
                },
                next: function () {
                    $.datepicker._adjustDate(id, +stepMonths, "M");
                },
                hide: function () {
                    $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
                },
                today: function () {
                    $.datepicker._gotoToday(id);
                },
                selectDay: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectDay(id, +this.getAttribute("data-month"), +this.getAttribute("data-year"), this);
                    return false;
                },
                selectMonth: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectMonthYear(id, this, "M");
                    return false;
                },
                selectYear: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectMonthYear(id, this, "Y");
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $(this).bind(this.getAttribute("data-event"), handler[this.getAttribute("data-handler")]);
        });
    },
```

Fix, replaced the argument 'id' in the handler functions with the 'inst.input'

```
    _attachHandlers: function(inst) {
        var stepMonths = this._get(inst, "stepMonths"),
            id = "#" + inst.id.replace( /\\\\/g, "\\" );
        inst.dpDiv.find("[data-handler]").map(function () {
            var handler = {
                prev: function () {
                    $.datepicker._adjustDate(inst.input, -stepMonths, "M");
                },
                next: function () {
                    $.datepicker._adjustDate(inst.input, +stepMonths, "M");
                },
                hide: function () {
                    $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
                },
                today: function () {
                    $.datepicker._gotoToday(inst.input);
                },
                selectDay: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectDay(inst.input, +this.getAttribute("data-month"), +this.getAttribute("data-year"), this);
                    return false;
                },
                selectMonth: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectMonthYear(inst.input, this, "M");
                    return false;
                },
                selectYear: function () {
                    $.datepicker._selectMonthYear(inst.input, this, "Y");
                    return false;
                }
            };
            $(this).bind(this.getAttribute("data-event"), handler[this.getAttribute("data-handler")]);
        });
    },
```

Comment: This works ! But how to do that .... in a clean way ?

Comment: The cleanest would be to fix it in the original jQuery ui code. I am still using the self modified jQuery-ui file(1.10). Could not confirm if this error still is present in 1.12 as there was a JQuery server bad gateway error on donwloading. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I run into same problem, maybe'll help to someone.

Just use same classes, and with same depth it'll work fine (at least for me it is).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've the datepicker control on one of the dialogs. This dialog uses     Something.cshtml. On this page, there is a provision to add child which is of same type. So, the dialog on the parent dialog also uses the same cshtml, as a result of which the id for the input is same. Now, when I select a date on the child dialog, it actually sets date on the parent dialog.

I've tried things like specifying the form name in each dialog.. like

```
* $("#frmChild .datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: Globalize.getPatternForDatapicker()});

* $("#frmChild input[id=StartDate]").datepicker({dateFormat: Globalize.getPatternForDatapicker()});
```

None of them worked for me. In either cases, it is setting date on the control on parent dialog.